# Static method doesn't return

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I did try to create a static method in my collection, but doesn't do the callback

My Code is:

//db.js

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    userId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },    
});


MySchema.statics.findDashboardByUserID = function (userid, callback) {
    console.log("id ===> "+userid);
    this.find({ userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid) }, 'name', callback);
};

MySchema.statics.findByName = function (name, callback) {
    console.log("name ===> "+name);
    this.find({ name: name }, 'index', callback);
};

// Build the MySchema model
var MySchema = mongoose.model('MySchema', MySchema);
```

//app.js

```
var mydb = require('./db');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MySchema = mongoose.model( 'MySchema' );

exports.getUserList = function (req, res) {

    MySchema.findByUserID(req.params.userid, function (err, user) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(user);
            res.json(user);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
            res.json({"status":"error", "error":"Error"});
        }
    });

    MySchema.findByName('foo', function (err, userName) {
        if(!err){
            console.log(userName);
            res.json(userName);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
            res.json({"status":"error", "error":"Error"});
        }
    });

};


//console
id ===> 77777777ffffff0000000011
name ===> First
```

I haven't a callback. and i never have console.log in my app.js, but i have only console.log in my db.js

Comment: I don't understand what you mean you haven't a callback - it looks like you have a callback and like it's being executed, hence the logs to the console. Can you try rephrasing or restating the question?

Comment: thanks for reply. I nerver have console.log(userName) o console.log(user); I have only console on db.js never in app.js